# Use an awk loop to subset a file

Tags: shell, loops, awk

I have a file with lots of pieces of information that I want to split on the first column.

Example (example.gen):

```
1 rs3094315 752566 A G 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1
1 rs2094315 752999 A G 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1
2 rs3044315 759996 A G 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1
2 rs3054375 799966 A G 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1
2 rs3094375 999566 A G 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1
3 rs3078315 799866 A G 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1
3 rs4054315 759986 A G 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1
4 rs4900215 752998 A G 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1
4 rs5094315 759886 A G 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1
4 rs6094315 798866 A G 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1
```

Desired output:

Chr1.gen

```
1 rs3094315 752566 A G 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1
1 rs2094315 752999 A G 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1
```

Chr2.gen

```
2 rs3044315 759996 A G 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1
2 rs3054375 799966 A G 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1
2 rs3094375 999566 A G 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1
```

Chr3.gen

```
3 rs3078315 799866 A G 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1
3 rs4054315 759986 A G 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1
```

Chr4.gen

```
4 rs4900215 752998 A G 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1
4 rs5094315 759886 A G 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1
4 rs6094315 798866 A G 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1
```

I've tried to do this with the following shell scripts, but it doesn't work - I can't work out how to get awk to recognise a variable defined outside the awk script itself.

First script attempt (no awk loop):

```
for i in {1..23}
do
    awk '{$1 = $i}' example.gen > Chr$i.gen
done
```

Second script attempt (with awk loop):

```
for i in {1..23}
do
    awk '{for (i = 1; i <= 23; i++) $1 = $i}' example.gen > Chr$i.gen
done
```

I'm sure its probably quite basic, but I just can't work it out...

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With awk:

```
awk '{print > "Chr"$1".gen"}' file
```

It just prints and redirects it to a file. And how is this file defined? With `"Chr" + first_column + ".gen"`.

With your sample input it creates 4 files. For example the 4th is:

```
$ cat Chr4.gen 
4 rs4900215 752998 A G 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1
4 rs5094315 759886 A G 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1
4 rs6094315 798866 A G 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1
```

Answer (score 3):

First, use @fedorqui's answer, as that is best. But to understand the mistake you made with your first attempt (which was close), read on.

---

Your first attempt failed because you put the test inside the action (in the braces), not preceding it. The minimal fix:

```
awk "\$1 == $i" example.gen > Chr$i.gen
```

This uses double quotes to allow the value of `i` to be seen by the `awk` script, but that requires you to then escape the dollar sign for `$1` so that you don't substitute the value of the shell's first positional argument. Cleaner but longer:

```
awk -v i=$i '$1 == i' example.gen > Chr$i.gen
```

This adds creates a variable `i` inside the `awk` script with the same value as the shell's `i` variable.